# Batch file to move file based on Month & Year on Date modified to folder with YYYY_MM

Tags: batch-file, file-io

Anyone can help me to create a batch file to move *.xml file from the X folder to YYYY_MM folder based on Month & year on date modified xml file?

I am not sure what to put inside the loop.

```
@echo off

echo Date is %Date%
dir /od/b "C:\Users\*.xml" > test.log
for /F %%f in (test.log) DO
(

)
```

at first I want to put `set var = %%~tf` inside the loop so that later I can use substring on var to get month and year and I can move the xml file to the YYYY_MM folder based on that, but seems that it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this[No **ROBOCOPY** required]:

```
 @echo off
    set "src=C:\test"
    set "dest=C:\test"
    for %%F in ("%src%\*") do (
      for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/ " %%A in ("%%~tF") do (
        if not exist "%dest%\%%C_%%A" mkdir "%dest%\%%C_%%A"
        move "%%~fF" "%dest%\%%C_%%A"
      )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you, i always forget the directory creation part for this kind of tasks. The robocopy usage is just to avoid the usual problems with different date formats in localized windows versions. But, as you are showing, it is `not needed` just a convenient option.

Comment: `%%~tF` is localised as well, and isn't reliable as a general solution because the format can change on any given computer.  Using Robocopy may be the better method.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who also wants to move subdirectories, adding to the answer of r3ap3r, here's a solution. Basically just add another for loop with the /d flag to loop through the sub directories:

```
@echo off
set "src=..\"
set "dest=..\archive"
for %%F in ("%src%\*") do (
  for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/ " %%A in ("%%~tF") do (
    if not exist "%dest%\%%C_%%A" mkdir "%dest%\%%C_%%A"
    move "%%~fF" "%dest%\%%C_%%A"
  )
)

for /d %%D in ("%src%\*") do (
  for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/ " %%A in ("%%~tD") do (
    if not exist "%dest%\%%C_%%A" mkdir "%dest%\%%C_%%A"
    move "%%~fD" "%dest%\%%C_%%A"
  )
)
```